# Неправильный запрос в БД

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$request = "insert into info1 values (NULL,$_POST['pib']);";
@mysql_query($request);
?>
```

что не так??

Comment: нашел 
$request="insert into info1 values (NULL,'".$_POST['pib']."');
но не пойму почему так надо делать, объясните

Comment: @hil400k потому что если в pib валяется строка `5, 17`, то это будет воспринято как два числа. А так, как вы делаете, делать вообще нельзя.

Comment: спасибо ,я просто учусь пока)
а строка 5 ,17 это что?

Comment: Плохая практика - писать в бд напрямую данные из пост и гет массивов. Это крупная дырень в безопасности. Экранируй их:
    addslashes($_POST['pib'])

при чтении из бд обратный результат можно получить так:
    stripslashes($request['field_name'])

Еще лучше - используй PDO http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php в это расширение, насколько я знаю, уже включена обработка подобных случаев. 

Но вообще, это может значить, что ты в поле текстового типа пытаешься записать int или другой. Сам мускль что пишет?

Comment: @hil400k - добавлю к вышесказанному: прочитайте про [prepared statement][1]

[1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$post = $_POST['pib'];
// далее проверяете $post на вредоносные символы, количество полученных символов, а затем -

<?php
$request = "insert into info1 values '$post');";
@mysql_query($request);
?>
```